# How to escape quotes using "echo"?

Tags: windows, cmd, escaping, echo, double-quotes

I am using the [Bitwarden CLI](https://bitwarden.com/help/cli/).
To pass a JSON to be encoded, it must be done using the command line. In particular, the pipe "|" operator.

On **Windows** is something like:

> echo "password": "defghi" | bw.exe encode

My problem is when there is a **quotation mark** inside the "password".
For example:

```bash
echo "password": "def"ghi" | bw.exe encode
```

The problem I am having is the output of the previous is as follow:

> "password": "def"ghi" | bw.exe encode

And the expected output should look like:

> ImFiYyI6ICJkZWZnaGkiIA0K

To share a **reproducible** example, try the following:

```bash
echo "abc": "def"ghi" | FIND "def"
```

Wrongly I get:

> "abc": "def"ghi" | FIND "def"

And expected output should be:

> "abc": "def"ghi"

I tried escaping the quotations using ^ and \.
I followed the proposals from this site https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html and https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Also tried with:

```bash
<nul set /p =""abc": "def"ghi" | FIND "def""
```

Is there any way to **escape** the quotation mark inside the password value? Thanks.

Comment: try to escape external quotes like this: **^"def"ghi^"**

Comment: @Daemon-5, worked like a charm. Please post your solution as an **Answer** so I can mark it as **solution**. Thanks!